# Exercise: Design a Stack

Tags: c#, beginner, stack, iterator, inheritance

> Exercise: Design a Stack
>
> A Stack is a data structure for storing a list of elements in a LIFO
>   (last in, first out) fashion. Design a class called Stack with three
>   methods.
>
> ```
> void Push(object obj)
> object Pop()
> void Clear()
> ```
>
> The `Push()` method stores the given object on top of the stack. We use
>   the “object” type here so we can store any objects inside the stack.
>   Remember the “object” class is the base of all classes in the .NET
>   Framework. So any types can be automatically upcast to the object.
>   Make sure to take into account the scenario that null is passed to
>   this object. We should not store null references in the stack. So if
>   null is passed to this method, you should throw an
>   `InvalidOperationException`. Remember, when coding every method, you
>   should think of all possibilities and make sure the method behaves
>   properly in all these edge cases. That’s what distinguishes you from
>   an “average” programmer.
>
> The `Pop()` method removes the object on top of the stack and returns
>   it. Make sure to take into account the scenario that we call the Pop()
>   method on an empty stack. In this case, this method should throw an
>   `InvalidOperationException`. Remember, your classes should always be in
>   a valid state and used properly. When they are misused, they should
>   throw exceptions. Again, thinking of all these edge cases, separates
>   you from an average programmer. The code written this way will be more
>   robust and with less bugs.
>
> The `Clear()` method removes all objects from the stack.
>
> We should be able to use this stack class as follows:
>
> ```
> var stack = new Stack();
>
> stack.Push(1);
> stack.Push(2);
> stack.Push(3);
>
> Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
> Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
> Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
> ```
>
> The output of this program will be
>
> ```
> 3
> 2
> 1
> ```

This was the task assigned to me.  Following is my code.

```
using System;

namespace Exercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var stack = new Stack();

            stack.Push(1);
            stack.Push(2);
            stack.Push(3);

            Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
            Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
            Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Exercise
{
    internal class Stack : IEnumerable
    {
        private object _object;
        private List<object> list = new List<object>();

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            while (list.Any())
                yield return Pop();
        }

        internal object Pop()
        {
            if (list.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use .Pop() if list count equals 0.");

            _object = list.FirstOrDefault();

            list.RemoveAt(0);

            return _object;
        }

        internal void Push(object obj)
        {
            _object = obj;

            if (_object == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use .Push() if object is null.");

            list.Insert(0, _object);
        }

        internal void Clear()
        {
            if (list.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use .Clear() if list is empty.");

            list.Clear();
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            if (list.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Stack is empty.");

            foreach (var s in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner in C#.  Is there anything left to improve on with this that is within the boundaries of what the instructions expect?  Any advice or suggestions if anything to teach me something new would be great.  Thank you for all the help so far on this site.

Comment: For others, these C# Intermediate Exercises came from Udemy and can be found mirrored at https://github.com/chrisvasqm/csharp-intermediate

Answer (score 5):

Questions:

1. Why do you use the class field `_object`? Does it serve any real purpose that a method-local variable cannot?
2. Why do you implement `IEnumerable`?
3. (only consider this if you have a decent understanding of concurrency issues, and want to practice) How can you make this code thread-safe?

Suggestions:

1. Several method throw exceptions in unexceptionable scenarios. Why do you blow up if I want to print or clear an empty stack? That's like having the waiter shoot herself if I try to order food right as the kitchen has closed.
2. When you're done with the exercise, consider making your stack generic. Casting from `object` is *so* old-school C#.
3. Consider improving your error messages. For one, `"Cannot use .Pop() if list count equals 0."` could be something like: "Cannot pop an element off an empty stack".

Comment: 1. ```_object = list.FirstOrDefault();``` and all other calls.  If you know of a way to replace this then by all means explain please?  No, I cannot remove the throw exceptions because the lesson requested it.  I am questioning whether you read this completely before responding.
2. I did so for the obvious reason, to get ```Print()``` to work.  If you have a suggestion to how to make it thread safe then enlighten me.  I was hoping someone would point stuff out so I could learn something new.

Comment: @Milliorn it seems you didn't understand the observation hidden inside question 1. The vast majority of questions in this answer seem to be rhethorical

Comment: @Vogel612 if  that is your opinion then by all means do explain it please.

Comment: @Milliorn the lesson requests throwing exception when pushing null and when popping empty stack. There is no indication that Print method should throw for empty stack nor there Is indication that Print method should exist. Also no indication that Clear should throw. Nor there Is indication that stack should be enumerable, nor there Is indication that it should be cleared when enumerated.

Comment: https://github.com/chrisvasqm/csharp-intermediate
@slepic

Comment: Yes I added Print, and yes the lesson said to cover all edge cases.  If people are going to be argumentative then why bother posting other than to aggravate someone looking for help.

Comment: @Milliorn You're taking it personaly. I have in no way tried to aggrevate you. If the choice of words sounds rude or in any way offensive, put that on the bill of a language barrier (I am not a native english speaker). Please re-read my previous comment carefully and treat it as constructive criticism. If something is not clear, ask for clarification of a specific part of my comment (or whatever)...

Answer (score 3):

You have posted several such exercises before, and I have commented on them as well.  First let's state the good: you are performing such exercises to improve your C# and .NET skills.  But I have noticed a pattern that if someone questions you on why you do some things a certain, you quickly take refuge under the blanket of that's what the exercise states.  But you also do things such as `Print()` all on your own.  To me, this seems to be conflicting goals among (1) you want to learn and improve, (2) you want to follow the strict letter of the exercise when it suits you, and (3) when it suits you, you want to diverge from the exercise.  This conflict may contribute to frustration others have when attempting to help you.

What caught my eye about your implementation was 2 notable things: (1) you rely heavily upon LINQ, and (2) you perform more expensive `Insert(0, item)` than to `Add(item)` to the end of list.

I take issue with `Pop()` because of `FirstOrDefault`.  Not because it's LINQ, although you do not need to use any LINQ at all in your solution.  Rather it's what it means.  First off, you check for emptiness that is Count == 0.  It would be better, i.e. more direct than for you to take list[0] because that's what the stack expects.  FirstorDefault just happens to return the first item for you, but what it really means is iterate over this list and find the first item that matches the predicate (and a null predicate means any item).  While it just happens to be that list[0] and FirstOrDefault works for you, they really mean 2 different things to someone reading your code.

Besides those observations, I would add the following remarks:

- The `internal` methods really should be `public`.
- `_object` does not need to be a class field or property.  It should be local to a method.
- I see no crime in clearing an empty list.  It may be pointless but it's less expensive than throwing an exception for it.  The edge case to consider would be if `list` was null, but it won't be.
- I would prefer to override `ToString()` instead of `Print()`.
- Console writes take a small bit of overhead, so it would be best to avoid repeated calls for every item in the list.  You can compose the string once with a fast `StringBuilder` and then write or return the string once.  Whether you write that string to the console or a log file is up to a developer using your stack.

**EDIT**

In light of @HenrikHansen 's answer about GetEnumerator, I have changed my answer to provide a custom enumerator.  I see some discussion between Henrik and @sleptic, so let me add some context.

Microsoft has this to say about [Stack.GetEnumerator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.8) :

```
Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they cannot be used to modify the underlying collection.
```

Also, out of furthering my own skills and providing a better answer, I borrowed some code from Microsoft's [Stack implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,8865095e0bceeafd), which uses an array BTW.

With that said, I offer the following modifications with updated code which now includes a better GetEnumerator:

```
public class StackV1 : IEnumerable
{
    private List<object> list = new List<object>();
    private int _version = 0; // used to keep in-sync with enumerator

    public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }

    public object Pop()
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty stack.  There is nothing to Pop().");
        }

        // Pop by removing from end of list.
        var index = list.Count - 1;
        var item = list[index];
        list.RemoveAt(index);

        _version++;

        return item;
    }

    public void Push(object item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(item)} is null.  There is nothing to Push().");
        }

        _version++;

        // Push by adding to end of list.
        list.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        // list will never be null, and it should not be a crime to clear an empty list.
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            list.Clear();
            _version++;
        }
    }

    public int Size => list.Count;

    // The original exercise did not require a Print() or ToString() method.
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            return "{ empty stack }"; // or perhaps "{ }"
        }

        // Each Console.WriteLine has a tiny cost.  Let's try not even call it, but rather comnpose a string.
        // This honors the OP's order and display.
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(list[i].ToString());
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    // See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,8865095e0bceeafd
    public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        private StackV1 _stack;
        private int _version;
        private int _index;
        private object currentElement;

        internal Enumerator(StackV1 stack)
        {
            _stack = stack;
            _version = stack._version;
            _index = -2;
            currentElement = default(object);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _index = -1;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            bool retval;
            if (_version != _stack._version)
            {
                throw new Exception("Out-of-sync Enumerator due to a modified Stack.");
            }
            if (_index == -2)
            {  // First call to enumerator.
                _index = _stack.Size - 1;
                retval = (_index >= 0);
                if (retval)
                {
                    currentElement = _stack.list[_index];
                }
                return retval;
            }
            if (_index == -1)
            {  // End of enumeration.
                return false;
            }

            retval = (--_index >= 0);
            currentElement = retval ? _stack.list[_index] : default(object);
            return retval;
        }

        public object Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (_index == -2)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Pointer is before top of the stack.");
                }
                if (_index == -1)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Pointer is past the bottom of the stack.");
                }
                return currentElement;
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            if (_version != _stack._version)
            {
                throw new Exception("Out-of-sync Enumerator due to the Stack being modified externally.");
            }
            _index = -2;
            currentElement = default(object);
        }
    }
}
```

Your original Print and my ToString list each item on a new line.  My personal preference would be to list as a collection like "{ 3, 2, 1 }"

```
// However my personal option would be to list as "{ 3, 2, 1 }"
sb.Append("{ ");
var first = true;
for (var i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var delimiter = first ? "" : ", ";
    sb.Append($"{delimiter}{list[i]}");
    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
    }
}
sb.Append(" }");
```

When I first looked at this exercise, I wondered why it was for Intermediates.  It seemed too easy.  After updating with a customer Enumerator, I can know see why its Intermediate.

The real fun would be to add generics for type-specific lists.  However, I see the exercise says that will be covered in an advanced exercise.  It's really not that much of a stretch and would be beneficial to the skills you wish to acquire.

Comment: Your observations are true.  I am trying to figure it out whichever way I can.  I added ```Print()``` because I wanted a way to see if not only what I was doing was correct, but to learn why I couldn't print ```Stack` with a ```foreach``` loop.  My intent is not to be confusing, although I can see how I can confuse others an myself.  If I rely on LINQ its simply because its what I am familiar with and not what might be what's best tool in my tool box.  The expensive functions I use are just familiar/easy for me to find and implement.  I ask for advice so I can learn what is optimal.

Comment: I have refactored this code.  This is the current state of it. [link](https://github.com/milliorn/Udemy/blob/master/C%23/C%23%20Intermediate%20Classes%2C%20Interfaces%20and%20OOP/4%20-%20Inheritance/5%20-%20Design%20a%20Stack/Stack.cs)

Comment: As for ```GetEnumerator``` that implementation I used to get ```Print``` to work was me looking through Stack Overflow post to see how to get this done.  I was trying to literally get something to print.  I had no idea if this was a good idea.  At that point I was trying to get anything to work with something I don't quite understand yet.  Thank you for posting your suggestions.  I am reading them now an trying to figure out what to merge.

Comment: ```The internal methods really should be public.``` Why is that?  I recall in the past people recommending what I thought was similar methods to be made ```internal```.  Guess I am now unsure why in this case they should be public? ```_object does not need to be a class field or property. It should be local to a method.``` That was done in my refactor.  Not sure why I did that to begin with. ```I see no crime in clearing an empty list.``` Is there a better way to do this like init/declare an empty list locally and returning it?

Comment: You mention about ```list.Count == 0``` so would ```if (!list.Any())``` be a better change?  If you check the link I posted above you can see the changes I made.  I want to add how you done Enumerator, but I feel like I need to omit it for now until I clearly understand everything that is going on there with your suggestion.  I feel like if I can't clearly explain it all then I shouldn't add it.

Comment: You should not be using LINQ for this.  Go for direct code.  Do you want to check to see if your stack is empty?  The most direct way to do this is check `list.Count == 0`.  Compare that to `list.Any()` which means enumerate over this collection to see if it has any elements.  The `Pop()` already ensures that no null elements are pushed on the stack, so really checking the `Count` is the most direct way to determine if the stack is empty or not.

Comment: @Milliorn Consider if you liked your custom stack so much that you wanted to publish it in a DLL for use within your organization.  You would want other consumers of the DLL to see certain things from their own projects, and that's why you would favor `public` over `internal` for this particular application.

Comment: I definitely got mixed up on that and all that I read.  Yes I want to use the most direct means to do that.  I'll change that back to ```list.Count == 0```

Answer (score 2):

One thing the other answers don't address is your implementation of `IEnumerable`:

> ```
>     public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
>     {
>         while (list.Any())
>             yield return Pop();
>     }
> ```

An iterator is supposed to iterate over all elements in the collection, but it should never ever change the state of the collection. Your implementation actual pops all the items in the stack, so it is empty afterwards.

Using it like:

```
var stack = new Stack();

stack.Push(1);
stack.Push(2);
stack.Push(3);

foreach (var item in stack)
{
   Console.PrintLine(item);
}
```

will result in an empty stack, and I don't think that should be the case.

If the top of the stack is the head of the list, you can just return the enumerator from the list:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
  return list.GetEnumerator();
}
```

---

You could make the private field `list` `readonly` to secure, that it is never set to `null` or anything else:

```
private readonly List<object> list = new List<object>();
```

---

Comment: I would object that Iterator must not change state of the container. I would say it Is uncommon, maybe unintuitive, but not forbidden. If you write it in the doc and maybe give it an expressive name, ie an explicit class DestructiveStackEnumerator... It should be fine for devs who read docs. Also iterating a stack is not necesary to go from top to bottom. Again it may be more intuitive, but not mandatory.

Comment: @slepic: I can only wish you all the best of luck :-)

Comment: Im not arguing that it is always good idea. I merely say that your claims are too strong. There sure are usecases where you want to iterate stack bottom to top, and/or in a destructive way. Though they may be much fewer, never say never. There is at least one widely used programming language in which a core stack implementation allows all of this by configuring the stack on instance level.

Comment: To be honest i can't remember when i needed to iterate a stack And direction was important. Most often i dont care what Is the direction as long as all items are iterated. Ie sum all numbers on the stack.

Comment: I agree with Henrik that addressing IEnumerable.GetEnumerator was lacking in other answers and that it should be discussed.  But I side with @slepic that enumerating should be non-destructive.  Microsoft also feels it should be non-destructive.  I have updated my answer with the Microsoft links as well as an improved GetEnumerator that uses a custom Enumerator.

Comment: @RickDavin yeah you have misinterpreted what both of us said :) Let me just stress out that I am not advocating for destructive iteration. I merely object that "never ever" Is too strong here, but i am absolutely fine with "should".

Comment: Sorry.  Got you guys switched.  Was rushing to update an answer during lunch before getting back to my real job.

Comment: @HenrikHansen ```One thing the other answers don't address is your implementation of IEnumerable:``` My implementation is based solely on me searching the web and trying to find something to work.  ```but it should never ever change the state of the collection``` I had no idea that was the case and yes that is not desirable here.  ```        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => list.GetEnumerator();``` Add that to my refactor.  I really need to learn more about IEnumerable.  Also changed list to be readonly.  Good catch on that one.  Thank you for and everyone else here for your help!

Comment: I would say that the nature of a `Stack` is to push and pop. The argument could be made that adding enumeration to it changes it to a different data structure. If it were a requirement to enumerate a stack, one could provide a `ToList()` method, which would change it into an enumerable data structure.

Comment: @Aron: I can only agree with you, but the generic stack from .net actually implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Henrik, thanks for the heads up on that. Apparently Microsoft takes a different philosophy on the capabilities of a stack. Fortunately, they also provide `ToList()`, so I can remain "pure." ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In reviewing the questions and answers it struck me that one way to simplify things would be to use linked list as the backing data structure instead of a `List` (which is based on an array).  A `LinkedList`, allows adding and removing from the "head" in O(1) without concern for an index. Sample code is below.

Additional points:

1. I agree with the others that a generic `Stack<T>` would be
   preferable.
2. I also agree that `_object` would be better as a local variable.
3. Rather than writing `list.Count == 0` multiple times, I
   created the `HasItems` property.
4. Adding the `Top` property allows the user to "peek" at the stack without popping.
5. At first I implemented `IEnumerable` but upon further consideration I realized that I would say that the nature of a `Stack` is to push and pop. The argument could be made that adding enumeration to it changes it to a different data structure. This prompted me to remove `IEnumerable` and add `ToList()`. Now a user can convert it to an `IEnumerable`, and work with that however they please. I also added a comment about this to the earlier answer.

Here is the sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class App_Stack
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var stack = new Stack();
        Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().ForEach(i => stack.Push(i));

        while (stack.HasItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((int)stack.Pop()).ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class Stack 
{
    private LinkedList<object> list = new LinkedList<object>();

    public object Top => list.FirstOrDefault();
    public int Count => list.Count;        
    public bool HasItems => Count > 0;

    public void Push(object item) => list.AddFirst(item);

    ///if stack is empty returns null
    public object Pop()
    {            
        var item = Top;
        if (HasItems)
        {                
            list.RemoveFirst();                
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is empty");
        }

        return item;
    }

    public void Clear() => list.Clear();

    public List<object> ToList() => list.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I added your suggestion ```HasItems```.  Also added the ```Top``` property but why not ```public object Top => list[0];```? [link to latest code](https://github.com/milliorn/Udemy/blob/master/C%23/C%23%20Intermediate%20Classes%2C%20Interfaces%20and%20OOP/4%20-%20Inheritance/5%20-%20Design%20a%20Stack/Stack.cs)

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. The risk with `Top => list[0]` is that when the list is empty it will throw an exception.

Comment: So either I use that and handle an exception, or pass a null?  Trying to make sure I am reading this right? (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Yes, `FirstOrDefault()` will return `list[0]` or `null`.

Comment: Also for the record, to get the last item in a list you could use `list.Last()` (or `list.LastOrDefault()`.